# Nonblocking and low latency method to pass values between two main loop threads?

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, thread-safety

In my project there is an audio thread updating with about 86 fps and a graphics thread which runs at 60 fps. Both threads can produce and consume values from each other.

But it is not necessary to consume every value, only the latest one is important and no notification is required because the threads just ask for a new value when they need one.

After reading tons of websites about threading I am a bit confused what I really need, because my task is quite simple. With locks my code would look like:

```
private T aField; //memory location

//other thread reads value
public void ReadValue(ref T val)
{
    lock(myLock) copy aField to val;
}

//this thread updates value
private void UpdateValue(T newVal)
{
    lock(myLock) copy newVal to aField;
}
```

My first question is, would this work for primitive types like float or int (<=32bit of size) without any lock because the copy is only one assignment which is atomic?

The next idea was a protection by a bool:

```
private T aField; //memory location
private volatile bool isReading;
private volatile bool isWriting;

//other thread reads value
public void ReadValue(ref T val)
{
    isReading = true;
    if(!isWriting) copy aField to val;
    isReading = false;
}

//this thread updates value
private void UpdateValue(T newVal)
{
    isWriting = true;
    if(!isReading) copy newVal to aField;
    isWriting = false;
}
```

Looks good to me but i am pretty sure i missed something. I could think of a worst case scenario when the faster thread reads while the slow thread wants to write. then the fast thread will read again the older value the next time, because no update was done.

What i also found was a nonblocking update method, but i wonder if and how it can help me:

```
static void LockFreeUpdate<T> (ref T field, Func <T, T> updateFunction)
  where T : class
{
  var spinWait = new SpinWait();
  while (true)
  {
    T snapshot1 = field;
    T calc = updateFunction (snapshot1);
    T snapshot2 = Interlocked.CompareExchange (ref field, calc, snapshot1);
    if (snapshot1 == snapshot2) return;
    spinWait.SpinOnce();
  }
}
```

What is the most efficient method with the lowest latency?

Comment: Your bool protection method creates *way* more problems than it solves.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz could you give me some details or point me to an example?

Comment: @thalm main problem that if conditions in both functions are false - neither update, nor read will occur, so you probably mean while - but in this case you can have deadloack, when both isreading and iswriting are true

Comment: ok, i can see the problem with both booleans are true, then nothing happens, which is ok in my case. but how can both booleans be false in the same time when both threads evaluate the if statement?

Comment: @thalm Because the compiler is free to optimize your code. If it sees you set a variable to true and then to false with no intervening reads, it is free to optimize out the first write. The logic is that it makes more sense to impose extra requirements on code that requires inter-thread synchronization than to reduce the possible optimizations for the 99% of code that doesn't.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz because of that i used the volatile keyword, which to my understanding prevents exactly these optimizations... or am i wrong on this?

Comment: @thalm For C#, you are correct. Be careful -- C and C++ have a `volatile` with completely different semantics.

Comment: Just use the lock. An uncontended lock will cost you something like 50 nanoseconds. A contended lock will be 50 nanoseconds plus the time to copy (a few microseconds for a large object?). You're only talking about two threads, so most of the problems associated with using locks incorrectly just aren't an issue. You might also consider [SpinLock](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Threading.SpinLock.aspx)

Comment: @JimMischel the problem is, that i have this part of the code everywhere... so it will be called hundreds of times every frame for different values all over the audio/video graph... 50ns can sum up pretty fast. the object size is not that big, most of the time one float or an array of 512 floats. i have to get rid of any unnecessary overhead...

Comment: So if the lock took 50 ns (on modern hardware it's much less--closer to 10 ns), then 1,000 calls for every frame at 86 fps, you're talking 4 milliseconds. That's worst case. And a `SpinLock` would be even cheaper. For atomic types (references, and 32-bit primitive types on 32-bit hardware, 64 and 32-bit primitive types on 64 bit hardware), you don't need the lock although then you have to be careful about compiler optimizations. For larger types you definitely need the lock.

Answer (score 1):

for your case you do not need any locks, just add volatile to private T aField; to prevent any possible compiler optimizations

Comment: But what happens if T is a more complex type or an array? The copy methods are critical here i think...

Comment: @thalm for complex types you need to go with any kind of locks, either explicit via lock or via spinwait as you described in 3rd option

Comment: @thalm If it's an array it's okay (as long as the array is placed in the read section only after it's fully populated and not modified) - reading/writing a reference is atomic IIRC.